# Can't deploy telegram bot on ubuntu server

Tags: python, firebase, telegram, ubuntu-18.04, telegram-bot

HI i've made `telegram bot` and trying to deploy it on `Ubuntu 18.04`

**Requirements:**

```
firebase==3.0.1
firebase-admin==4.3.0
pyTelegramBotAPI==3.7.1
grpcio==1.29.0
requests==2.23.0
```

I installed this on server:

```
build-essential
libssl-dev
libffi-dev
python3-pip
python3-dev
python3-setuptools
python3-venv
```

After creating venv, i go to /etc/systemd/system/ and made uba.service

**uba.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=uba
After=network.target
 
[Service]
User=uba
Group=uba
 
WorkingDirectory=/home/kokoto/uba/
Environment="PYTHONPATH=/home/kokoto/uba/"
ExecStart=/home/kokoto/uba/.venv/bin/python /home/kokoto/uba/bot_bd.py
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when i'm running bot, i have this errors:

```
uba.service - uba
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uba.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-09-21 17:48:05 MSK; 16h ago
Process: 10282 ExecStart=/home/kokoto/uba/.venv/bin/python /home/kokoto/uba/bot_bd.py (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)
Main PID: 10282 (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)

Sep 21 17:48:05 s307229 systemd[1]: Started uba.
Sep 21 17:48:05 s307229 systemd[10282]: uba.service: Failed to determine group credentials: No such process
Sep 21 17:48:05 s307229 systemd[10282]: uba.service: Failed at step GROUP spawning /home/kokoto/uba/.venv/bin/python: No such process
Sep 21 17:48:05 s307229 systemd[1]: uba.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP
Sep 21 17:48:05 s307229 systemd[1]: uba.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but may be ubuntu uses python2 version. Try to change `python` to `python3`

```
ExecStart=/home/kokoto/uba/.venv/bin/python3 /home/kokoto/uba/bot_bd.py
```